# SP2016 - Change Suite Bar?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2016

I'm tinkering with SharePoint 2016 RTM and I'm trying to change the top link bar, where at the top it says "SharePoint | Sites". I'd like to change it so that instead of it saying SharePoint, it says something like Intranet

I've been using the following powershell commands, which work in SP2013 but dont seem to work or do anything in SP2016. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$myApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sp2016"
$myApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = '<div class="ms-core-brandingText"><a style="color:#fff;" href="http://sp2016">Intranet</a></div>
$myapp.Update()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of new Commands in SharePoint 2016. You can try those.

```
$web = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sp2016
$web.SuiteNavBrandingLogoNavigationUrl ="http://google.com"
$web.SuiteNavBrandingLogoTitle = "Test"
$web.SuiteNavBrandingLogoUrl = "Url of the Logo"
$web.SuiteNavBrandingText ="testing"
$web.Update()
```

I am not sure why your stuff is not working may be HTML change, not sure.

If you want to just link the branding text element to a URL, you can use a clear PNG file for the logo URL. There doesn't seem to be a way just yet to link the branding text otherwise.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Do you know how I can make the "Intranet" a hyperlink that returns back to the web application root?

Comment: Funny thing setting SuiteNavBrandingText doesn't change a thing on this one 2016 environment (16.0.4534.1000) I'm working on. Yes, have run web.Update(). :)

Comment: how to remove these custom links from top suite bar after adding them with above powershell method?

Comment: Zakir have you tried running the same script and pass an empty text " " ??

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://sp2016
$wa.SuiteNavBrandingText = "Intranet"
$wa.Update()
```

Comment: +1 for using $wa instead of $web.

Comment: how to remove these custom links from top suite bar after adding them with above powershell method?

Answer (score 0):

You can 
- set the blank logo image by `SuiteNavBrandingLogoUrl` 
- set your desire url to `SuiteNavBrandingLogoNavigationUrl`.

After that top left corner "SharePoint" will be clickable.

You can also change the test from "SharePoint" to anything by using  `SuiteNavBrandingText` property.