# Customise SharePoint text site SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, site

Does anyone know where I go to customise the below text on my sharepoint 2016 site?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is Powershell script available to allow you to change the text. `SuiteNavBrandingLogoTitle` value specifies the text and you can also change the URL it redirects to using `SuiteNavBrandingLogoNavigationUrl`

```
$web = Get-SPWebApplication "http://mywebapp"
$web.SuiteNavBrandingLogoNavigationUrl ="http://mywebapp.sharepoint.com"
$web.SuiteNavBrandingLogoTitle = "MyWebApp"
$web.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Suite Bar text using few lines of PowerShell script.

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://sp2016
$wa.SuiteNavBrandingText = "Intranet"
$wa.Update()
```

For additional customizations, you can refer below post.

[SP2016 - Change Suite Bar?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177733/sp2016-change-suite-bar)